# Does networkx's weighted edge_betweenness_centrality algorithm need distances or similarities would work too?

Tags: python-3.x, algorithm, networkx, graph-theory

So I have an undirected graph comprised of edges that have a weight (a similarity score). I am running
networkx's weighted  `edge_betweenness_centrality` algorithm and have some results.

However it has occured to me that the algorithm needs distances to work properly as its based on shortest paths distance calculations. Unfortunately the [documentation](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/generated/networkx.algorithms.centrality.edge_betweenness_centrality.html?highlight=edge_betweenness_centrality#networkx.algorithms.centrality.edge_betweenness_centrality) is lacking in regards to making this clear so I wanted to ask if anyone can indeed confirm this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming, that since you have a weighted graph, you've set those weights to the distances between edges. In that case, `nx.edge_betweenness_centrality` takes a `weight` parameter:

> **weight**: (None or string, optional (default=None)) – If None, all edge weights are considered equal. Otherwise holds the name of the edge attribute used as weight.

By setting it to the name of the weight attribute, the shortest paths required to compute the centrality measure will be calculated via `_single_source_dijkstra_path_basic`, which takes a `weight` parameter, so the final measure will take the distances into account.

Comment: My weights are similarities. But from your answer I see that it should be a distance and not a similarity. So my weight needs to be (1-similarityscore).

Comment: That makes sense to me yes @Mamonu